# how does antivirus works?

Tags: antivirus

What are the basic working principles of an antivirus program?

Comment: First hit on google using "how does antivirus works" http://www.antivirusworld.com/articles/antivirus.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it matches patterns of known viruses with each file.

for example change the executable into a histogram and compare the similarity between that executable and known viruses.

another way is to scan for design patterns such as polymorphisism and comparing those to, this can lead to false positives (in very complex apps) but also catch unknown viruses.

Answer (score 1):

A antivirus reads trough all files and searches for patterns of known viruses in the files.

Comment: Hi powtac,what does it mean by pattern?

Comment: For example if a virus contains code which deletes files from you harddisk, this piece of code can be used as a pattern.